# как сделать кастомным заголовок HeaderView в tableView, и указать секцию?

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview

Всем привет и извините за повтор вопроса.Не могу указать объекту в headere секцию.Я с группировал ячейку с хедером, они соединились и ячейки не заходят под хедер.Но почему то картинка делает анимацию и сжимается, разжимается.Я понял что нужно задать  обьектам секцию, задаю и выдает ошибку STRING. Так вот у меня имеется класс объектов в Parse раздел Soccer.Из нее у меня половина объектов идет в Tableview обычная таблица с списком матчем, потом унаследовал обьекты, вторая часть которая пойдет в детальную сцену.Когда указываю их, и не пишу indexPath.row и присвою объект с сервера то все нормально отображается.Но как сделать что в секции их указывают, вот проблема для меня. Пробывал делать объект писал и указывал в функции Header title string, то нормально отображалось. Очень буду благодарен за помощь.Мой код.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    var detailSoccer: Soccer!

    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "CustomSoccerHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 350
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 288
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.reloadData()
        loadMatchSoccer()
        //Headerc

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 300
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView") as! CustomSoccerHeaderView
        header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 350)

        header.nameHeader.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS
        return header
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell") as! SoccerTableViewCell

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Аналитика и обзор матча:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.textSoccer
        case 1:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.detailPrognozS
        default:
            break
        }



        return soccerCell


    }






    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }






    func loadMatchSoccer() {

        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
        query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.selectedSoccer = objects!

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему в методе высоты хедера высота 300, а при инициализации хедера высота 350 ?

Comment: Я указал приблизительно как должно быть.Я сделал все по 350, все равно картинка немного тянется, как ее сделать чтоб не тянулась.Очень буду благодарен.Из за чего оно может быть.Задать может надо ее размер CGRECT?